How to resolve date in android kotlin
In my android app, I have a model with an attribut Date(). But when I create this model, the date is creating with -2 hours. I have tried to resolve this with a method to change the time zone to UTC.
private fun getCurrentUTC(): Date { val calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")) return calendar.time }
and I call this method in my attribut date in the model
var date: Date = getCurrentUTC()
So, my front sends the bad date but in my backend (spring boot java), it receives the good date but it save
`date before save in db : Sun Jun 02 17:33:14 CEST 2024
in my db with the bad date (-2hours). I don't ubnderstand what's happend.
and it's return the object with the bad date
"date":"2024-06-02T15:33:14.356+00:00",
I have searched in stackoverflow and what I tried it was wrong.

Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Use LocalDate from java.time,., the modern Java date and time API for a date. Don’t use Datenor Calendar. They had severe design problems and are now long outdated. For one thing a Date was always in UTC and never printed that way

I don’t quite get the whole picture. Can you give an example of the bad date that the front-end sends and tell us what you wanted it to send instead? And create a [mre] producing that bad date?
